# How to remove NAT for my VM Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cpanel, nat

I just created a VM instance with a static IP address to install cpanel.

It turns out that cPanel has some problems with NAT. Also cPanel does not provide technical support for systems with NAT.

Now I want to disable/remove NAT in my VM instance. Otherwise I will never be able to use cPanel on it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if by saying NAT you mean Network Address Translation, you can't remove it from your VM instance due to NAT is allocated in your router. You need instead to forward a port in your router to your VM's local port. If you're using cPanel, the standard port should be 2082. The reason to forward a port is to enable all incoming packages to be redirected from you router's external (global static or dynamic)IP to your VM's local IP, from router's port to local port. Try to check out your router settings and find port forwarding option there. Also try to google for web-server behind NAT.

Comment: Yes I meant "Network Address Translation".
I need to completely disable NT somehow. And not just for accessing cpanel on port 2083, but nearly for every other protocol like ftp, smtp, ssh, etc.
I don't see a port option in VPC Networks->Routes in the console.
Please help.

Comment: Ok, let's try to find out some detailes. Please tell me the model of your router. I meant you try to find port forward option directly in your router, not in VPC. By default router can be accessed at 192.168.0.1 for example, IP, user name and password - they all depand on a model type. So tell me your model name, I'll google how to adjust it to your needs. It should work. I beleive it's not a software problem, but a hardware one instead.

Comment: I am extremely sorry.
I forgot to mention that I am on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Wow... I don't even know what to say, I've never used Google Cloud Platform, may be this article would be helpful https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations, at least it describes how to create a firewall instance on a given VM, so there definitely must be some sort of commands to disable NAT, sorry, I'm absolute noob here.